# Is the following norm stronger given that the convergence induced is stronger?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ normed space with two norms $(X,|\cdot|_1),(X,|\cdot|_2)$. 
Suppose that for every $x_n,x \in X$ such that $|x_n-x|_2\to 0$ then $|x_n-x|_1\to 0$ so that the convergence induced by $|\cdot|_2$ is stronger then the one induced by $|\cdot|_1$ and hence the topology induced by $|\cdot|_2$ is stronger.
Now in this framework is it possible to prove
$$|x|_1 \leq C |x|_2$$
so that also the norm $|\cdot|_2$ is stronger then $|\cdot|_1$?

To me it seems not the case.

Comment: The identity map from $(X,|\cdot|_2)$ to $(X,|\cdot|_1)$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes so it trivially holds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that $\sup_{x\ne 0}\|x\|_1/\|x\|_2=\infty.$ Then   for each $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ let $x_n\ne 0$ with $\|x_n\|_1>n\|x_n\|_2.$ Then let $y_n=x_n/ (\|x_n\|_2\cdot \sqrt n).$ But then $\|y_n\|_2\to 0$ and $\|y_n\|_1>\sqrt n,$ contrary to $\|y_n-0\|_2\to 0\implies \|y_n-0\|_1\to 0.$

Comment: Footnote: A similar result for metric spaces in general does NOT hold. E.g. let $X=\Bbb R$ with $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and with $x\ne y\implies d_2(x,y)=1.$ Then $d_2(x_n,x)\to 0\implies \{n: x_n\ne x\}$ is finite $\implies d_2(x_n,x)\to 0.$ But $\sup_{x\ne y}d_1(x,y)/d_2(x,y)=\infty.$